# Nodejs and Express: long time to load page

Tags: node.js, express

I've created my first app with Nodejs and Express. It's working fine, but it's slow to load pages when navigating from one route to another. I put a log inside the pages to see what happens and apparently the delay occurs between the page call and the rendering, ie it seems (I think ...) it seems to be the server's time to return the reply, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know what I can do to decrease page load time?

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cancela",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "log": "^1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0",
    "pm2": "~2.6.1",
    "pug": "~2.0.0-beta11",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Turn on Express [**debug**](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html).

Comment: Very cool!! I've discovered that the longer time is in PUG Views rendering. But there's another thing I've noticed: when I open one of my routes where I use `socket.io`, that page run a function update every 100ms. And even after switching to another page, `socket.io` stays active in the background as if the page was still open (but I'm already on another page ...). I think that's a problem too, isn't it?

Comment: Try set [**`transports`**](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#) as `['websocket', 'polling']` on server-side. This behavior like a `polling`. I don't think that it's  a big problem.

Comment: You will likely have to show your PUG template and all subtemplates being used and all code that is running as part of the render.  We can't help you figure out why it takes 3 seconds to render a page without seeing the template and code involved in that operation!  And please keep your separate comments about socket.io to a new and different question since it does not appear to have anything to do with rendering.

Comment: OK jfriend00! Thanks @AikonMogwai

Answer (score 1):

Are you in dev mode ? if yes, that's because caching and other way isn't activated. When you will move to production, caching will be activated and your nodejs won't need to reload and parse every html page

But what's your current page load time ?

Comment: I 've edited my question and it includes my `package.json` ... I'm no longer in dev time. The time to load a page is between 2 and 3 seconds. I'm accessing my pages from a PC connected directly to the server via cross cable.

Comment: is the problem on all pages or only pages with mysql ? 
Because I don't see something really heavy or a big  dependency which could need 2s to load on each page
If you test with another browser is the same time? what is you server ?

Comment: I think you've already shown me what the biggest problem is. In the pages where MySQL requires the loading is slower, in the others it's faster. Even so, it's a bit slow on the fastest pages, between 0.5 and 1.5 seconds. My "server" is not a server properly. It's a single board that runs stand alone. It's a Beaglebone Black, that is, low speed. But I still think it's taking too long ...